# Parsing XML with more than one element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, .net-4.5

I am finding it difficult to parse the below xml structure (using c#.net 4.5) and store in the DB (Sql-Server).

I know how to parse as long as there is one attribute of each record e.g. Publisher; Date(Year) but as you see from the structure within authors there is more than one, which is where I am struggling.

I use XmlNodeList, XmlNode and InnerText to extract the data from each element.

Appreciate your time and assistance

**XML Structure**

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <title></title>
    <date>
      <year></year>
    </date>
    <Link></link>
    <summary></summary>
    <publisher>
      <name></name>
    </publisher>
    <authors total="2">
      <author>
        <name></name>
      </author>
      <author>
        <name></name>
      </author>
    </authors>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

I have now attached the code that I am using which works fine except  (because of it having more than one attribute unlike others)

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(/*Here I pass the xml which has been stored in string variable. The structure of which has been in my original post*/);
                XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Books[@*]");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    XmlNodeList anodes = xn.SelectNodes("Book");
                    foreach (XmlNode node in anodes)
                    {
                        if (anodes != null)
                        {
                            titles.Add(node["title"].InnerText);  //titles is an list
                            summarys.Add(node["summary"].InnerText);//Summarys is an list
                            link.Add(node["Link"].InnerText);//link is an list
                            counter +=1;
                                }
                      }
                            XmlNodeList CNodes = xn.SelectNodes("Book");
                            foreach (XmlNode node2 in CNodes)
                            {
                                XmlNode example = node2.SelectSingleNode("date");
                                if (example != null)
                                {
                                    years.Add(example["year"].InnerText);//years is an list
                                }
                            }
                            XmlNodeList dNodes = xn.SelectNodes("Book");
                            foreach (XmlNode node3 in dNodes)
                            {
                                XmlNode example1 = node3.SelectSingleNode("publisher");
                                if (example1 != null)
                                {
                                    publishers.Add(example1["name"].InnerText);//publishers is an list
                                }
                            }

                           XmlNodeList fnodes = xn.SelectNodes("Book/authors/author/name");
                                foreach (XmlNode node5 in fnodes)
                                {

                                    authors.Add( node5 != null ? node5.InnerText : "");//authors is an list. For the first book i need to store in list[0] and next in list[1]

                                    }
                            }
        // Convert list to array
                            titles.ToArray();
                            summarys.ToArray();
                            urls.ToArray();
                            years.ToArray();
                            publishers.ToArray();
                            authors.ToArray();
```

Comment: "*which is where I am struggling*" How are you struggling? Can you show us a code snippet so we can get a sense of where exactly things aren't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you:

```
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("asd");
            var book = (from b in xDoc.Descendants("Book")
                select new Book
                {
                    Title = b.Element("title").Value,
                    Year = b.Element("date").Element("Year").Value,
                    Link  = b.Element("link").Value,
                    Summary = b.Element("summary").Value,
                    Publisher = b.Element("publisher").Element("name").Value,
                    Authors = (from a in b.Element("authors").Elements("author")
                                   select a.Element("name").Value).ToList(),
                }).First();
```

Book class:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

PS: XDocument class is under the System.Xml.Linq namespace

Comment: Thanks Selman22, also looking into your logic now. Please have a look at my updated post (code attached) and provide your comments, if any.